# Extract multiple images from image using Javascript or Jquery only without using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**PS : For requirements for this project use Javascript or Jquery, i can't use CSS.**

I need to extract images from image and display in div using javascript and html.

I try using this image : 
 
[image]

**For information this image is just for test and base in solution i will adapt in real world image project.**

I want to get this 2 images and display in my div using img dom in my HTML.

[image]

[image]

For this purpose i try to adapt this work `http://jsfiddle.net/yn1tworg/6/` to work for me. But without success.

Anyone have a idea how to resolve this issue, or `jsfiddle.net` work plz share with me and thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't be done with javascript.  You should be able to use css to carve out specific quadrants of the sprite map for your usage. Edit: random google, https://citsf221.community.uaf.edu/07-navigation-image-maps-css-sprites/

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS and just play with `background-position` until the image is what you need to be.

```css
#box{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YWPU.png);
    background-position: 280px -260px;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use clip CSS peoperty --

```
    <div style="padding: 300px;">
        <img src="./overflow_files/3YWPU.png" style="position: absolute;clip: rect(260px,730px,380px,600px);">
        
            
        </div>
```